# WPF Socket Connections

Tags: wpf

I really think that here ill found my answers...
I try to make a server-client app in WPF, I try to use TcpClient and TcpListener..
another connection ideas will be welcome

doe's someone know how to make a server-client connection in WPF??
code example can be very usefull..
hank you all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> doe's someone know how to make a server-client connection in WPF??

The same way you would do it in any other kind of app. WPF is just a UI, it is completely unrelated to client/server aspects of the application.